# C++ Free pointers stored in a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, runtime-error, delete-operator

So, I have these functions (`Game` inherits from `GameInterface`; they both currently have no purpose, I'm just testing whether what I have in mind can be done or not.):

```
vector<GameInterface*> Game::generateChildren() {
    vector<GameInterface*> vgf;        
    // make 10 copies of this object, increasing the 'npawns' attribute
    Game* gi = this;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        gi = new Game(*gi);
        vgf.push_back(gi);
        ++gi->npawns;
    }
    return vgf;
}
```

and

```
const int Library::getBestMovement(GameInterface* gf) const {
    vector<GameInterface*> vgf = gf->generateChildren();
    int nchildren = vgf.size();

    // outputs "child #i has (i+1) pawns" for i in 0..9
    for (int i = 0; i < nchildren; ++i) {
        cout << "child #" << i << " has " << vgf[i]->num_of_pawns() << " pawns" << endl;
    }

    // missing some dynamic memory management (deleting the pointers in vgf)

    return 0;
}
```

Since the "children" objects are created with `new`, and they will no longer be used once `getBestMovement` ends, I assume I have to free the pointers inside `vgf`.

The problem is that I've tried everything from

```
for (auto it = vgf.begin(); it != vgf.end(); ++it)
    delete *it;
```

to using *smart pointers*, but I always get the same debug assertion error when I execute the program: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse).

Any idea about what the problem is? Thanks

EDIT:

Ok, I had `class Game : virtual public GameInterface`. Removed the `virtual` keyword and it works fine now. I don't know why, though (I didn't even know what he `virtual` keyword did; I'm mostly testing stuff since I'm kind of new to the language, so please bear with me)

EDIT 2:

Forcing the `GameInterface` destructor to be virtual seems to be the proper solution.

Comment: How was `Game::Game(const Game&)` defined?

Comment: I'd recommend to use something like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameInterface>>` instead, which would take care of the memory management correctly.

Comment: If you use a smart pointer, you really should be using smart pointers *everywhere*. Make sure no part of any code is being passed a plain `GameInterface*`.

Comment: The source code of `Game::~Game()` implementation would also be helpful

Comment: the default copy constructor works just fine (`Game` only has the integer `npawns`, and the output is the one we expect).

Comment: Does `GameInterface` have a virtual destructor?

Comment: Why on earth there are still people using vector<X*> in c++11 era?

Comment: @KerrekSB `GameInterface` only has a pure virtual function. What is a virtual destructor and when should I use one? Maybe it has to do with the "solution" I added at the end of the post?

Comment: @icando because I'm just a student who's been taught basic stuff and has never had the need to use anything more complex. What would you recommend?

Comment: @and.ml: Without a virtual destructor your code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @and.ml: Your code doesn't "work fine now". It's still broken, even if it appears to do what you expect.

Comment: @and.ml `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameInterface>>`, as other people mentioned.  If you are taught to use `vector<X*>`, punch on the face of your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should be vaguely correct:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct GameInterface
{
    virtual ~GameInterface() {}
    virtual std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameInterface>> generateChildren() = 0;
};

struct Game : GameInterface
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameInterface>> generateChildren() override
    {
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<GameInterface>> result;

        for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
        {
            result.emplace_back(new Game(result.empty()
                                         ? *this
                                         : *result.back()));
            ++result.back()->npawns;
        }

        return result;
    }
};

int getBestMovement(GameInterface* gf)
{
    auto v = gf->generateChildren();

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new Game(*this)` has different behavior than original code